# Tensorflow: logistic regression to mnist

Tags: python, tensorflow

I try to use logistic regression to mnist dataset, but I have some problem with realization

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_digits
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score

s = tf.InteractiveSession(config=tf.ConfigProto(gpu_options=gpu_options))

mnist = load_digits(2)

X,y = mnist.data, mnist.target

# inputs and shareds
weights = tf.Variable(np.zeros((64, 1), dtype='float32'))
input_X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 64))
input_y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 1))

predicted_y = tf.add(tf.matmul(input_X, weights), input_y)
loss = tf.losses.log_loss(input_y, predicted_y)

optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=1e-2).minimize(loss)
train_function = s.run(optimizer, feed_dict={input_X: X, input_y: y.reshape(-1, 1)})
predict_function = s.run(predicted_y, feed_dict={input_X: X})

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y)

for i in range(5):
    s.run(optimizer)
    loss_i = s.run(loss, feed_dict={input_X: X_test, input_y: y_test})

    print("loss at iter %i:%.4f" % (i, loss_i))

    print("train auc:",roc_auc_score(y_train, predict_function(X_train)))
    print("test auc:",roc_auc_score(y_test, predict_function(X_test)))


print ("resulting weights:")
plt.imshow(weights.eval().reshape([8,8]))
plt.colorbar()
```

The problem appears when I try to run `train_prediction`. It returns

```
FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value Variable_16
 [[Node: Variable_16/read = Identity[T=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@Variable_16"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](Variable_16)]]
```

I try to change shape of the inputs, but I can't understand, what's wrong.

Comment: what is s? This is not MVCE

Comment: @mad_ , sorry, `s = tf.InteractiveSession(config=tf.ConfigProto(gpu_options=gpu_options))`

Answer (score 0):

TensorFlow documentation explicitly says:

> When you launch the graph, variables have to be explicitly initialized before you can run Ops that use their value. You can initialize a variable by running its initializer op, restoring the variable from a save file, or simply running an assign Op that assigns a value to the variable. In fact, the variable initializer op is just an assign Op that assigns the variable's initial value to the variable itself.

Therefore, after opening a TF session, you must initialize your `weight` variable running one of the [Initializer Op](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/initializers).

I suggest you to define new variables using `tf.get_variable()` which create a new variable or retrieve an existing one given the name you provide as argument. In its parameter list, there's the possibility to pass a `tf.initializer`, but if you do not do that, it will load the default initializer.